# Accessing PHP associative array with index represented as string

Tags: php, associative-array

Is it possible to do something like this in PHP?

```
$index1 = "[0][1][2]";
$index2 = "['cat']['cow']['dog']";

// I want this to be $myArray[0][1][2]
$myArray{$index1} = 'stuff';

// I want this to be $myArray['cat']['cow']['dog']
$myArray{$index2} = 'morestuff';
```

I've searched for a solution, but I don't think I know the keywords involved in figuring this out.

Comment: You could do this with eval() but I recommend against using it. Could we ask why you want to do this? There might be another way to accomplish what you want :)

Comment: I am writing a recursive function the alters different dimension of an array.  If you pass, `$array['cow']` into a function, I'm pretty sure you cannot access `$array` from that function (even if passed by reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly. `$myArray[$index]` would evaluate to `$myArray['[0][1][2]']`. You would probably have to separate each dimension or write a little function to interpret the string:

```
function strIndexArray($arr, $indices, $offset = 0) {
     $lb = strpos($indices, '[', $offset);
     if ($lb === -1) {
         return $arr[$indices];
     }
     else {
         $rb = strpos($indices,']', $lb);
         $index = substr($indices, $lb, $rb - $lb);
         return strIndexArray($arr[$index], substr($indices, $rb+1));
     }
}
```

You can probably find some regular expression to more easily extract the indices which would lead to something like:

```
$indices = /*regex*/;
$value = '';
foreach($indices as $index) {
    $value = $array[$index];
}
```

To set a value in the array the following function could be used:

```
function setValue(&$arr, $indices, $value) {
    $lb = strpos($indices, '[');
    if ($lb === -1) {
        $arr = $value;
    }
    else {
        $rb = strpos($indices, ']', $lb);
        $index = substr($indices, $lb, $rb);
        setValue($arr[$index], substr($indices, $lb, $rb+1), $value);
    }
}
```

Note: I made above code in the answer editor so it may contain a typo or two ; )

Comment: I just realized my answer is not a solution as it's only to get a value and the question asker wants to set a value.

Comment: I'm trying to think of a regex solution, but what would happen if you come across `$index = "['[a]']";.  I think the possible input for a general solution might be too complex for one.

Comment: In that case the thing would break and use the `'[a` as index, then again, it uses that index both for getting and setting so all is not lost. Besides that, I've never in my life used a `[` or `]` in an array index, but I can understand that's just me.

Comment: I picked this one, because it shows the coder clear intent of what the code is accomplishing.  To anyone reading this, `eval()` could be an acceptable solution,  but having a function call with the intent is much better in practice.

Comment: Re the ['[a]'], a check of `$lb2 = strpos($indices,'[',$lb); $lb2 < $rb;` could catch that special case.

Answer (score 4):

```
eval('$myArray[0][1][2] = "stuff";');
eval('$myArray'.$index1.' = "stuff";');
```

But be careful when using eval and user input as it is vulnerable to code injection attacks.

Comment: gahh, is `eval()` the only solution?

Comment: You could also do it the dirty way and parse your $index string and then loop though the array levels. interested in this approach?

Comment: `eval` might not be the only solution, but it is the *best* one. `eval` is *exactly* what you are looking for. Please don't mindlessly ignore the best solution just because you've heard people say "eval is evil".

Comment: well eval *is* evil, I usually look for all possible solutions before using it!

Comment: @meager But it is! :O Also, you might want to test for speed in eval vs. a parser function as eval will need to parse the code too before executing it so the parser function might be as fast or faster than eval and safer too.

Comment: `eval` is not evil. You just have to be careful when using it. It may also be disabled on your server, so try it before implementing anything. I also don't think that `eval` will perform well compared to directly accessing `$myArray[1][2][3]`.

Comment: @afuzzyllama "X is evil, never use X" is *not* a valid opinion, and it smacks of ignorance. Evil keywords don't exist, there are only *bad programmers*.

Comment: Guys be cool. We are all friends here. Everybody is allowed to believe what they want. We don't discuss opinions, we discuss arguments.

Answer (score 1):

```
$index1 = "[0][1][2]";
$index2 = "['cat']['cow']['dog']";

function myArrayFunc(&$myArray,$myIndex,$myData) {
    $myIndex = explode('][',trim($myIndex,'[]'));
    $m = &$myArray;
    foreach($myIndex as $myNode) {
        $myNode = trim($myNode,"'");
        $m[$myNode] = NULL;
        $m = &$m[$myNode];
    }
    $m = $myData;
}

// I want this to be $myArray[0][1][2]
myArrayFunc($myArray,$index1,'stuff');

// I want this to be $myArray['cat']['cow']['dog']
myArrayFunc($myArray,$index2,'morestuff');


var_dump($myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's always the evil eval:

```
eval('$myArray' . $index1 . ' = "stuff";');
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use two anonymous functions for this.

```
$getThatValue = function($array){ return $array[0][1][2]; };
$setThatValue = function(&$array, $val){ $array[0][1][2] = $val; };

$setThatValue($myArray, 'whatever');
$myValue = $getThatValue($myArray);
```

Comment: I understood the question to mean `"[0][1][2]"` was variable.

Comment: he wants it the other way around :)

Comment: What happens if the indexes change?